# Getting the HTML source code of an .swf URI

Tags: php, curl, flash, scrape

I was wondering whether one could get the HTML source code from an .swf URI?

For instance a web page such as:

http://media.flixfacts.com/360view/acer_uk/002/acer_uk-002-en.swf

When I use curl to scrape this page it brings back the swf source not the html source.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand - an .SWF file is Flash, not HTML.

Comment: @Crontab Firefox shows the swf is embeded in an html format. I guess firefox is doing its own interpreting.

Comment: It's because the web browser needs to make assumptions when displaying that particular type of file.  FF expects a Flash file to be embedded in a page, so when it finds the page missing it builds its own page.  Chrome and IE do the same thing, though the code they all generate is a little different from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's confusing/unexpected - you're not scraping an HTML file, you're scraping a SWF file (which is a binary format, so you're likely getting a bunch of gibberish).

**Bottom Line:** *There is no HTML in a SWF file.*

Comment: Ok. I'm getting confused then because firefox shows an embeded element in html when you look at the source. Firefox must be interpreting this itself.

Answer (score 1):

SWF is the extension of Flash files. They don't *have* HTML. They're an utterly different proprietary format. The only thing that will display Flash files is Flash Player, or some programs can extract the resources (images, sounds, and so on) inside them.